# Is LM3914 protected from reverse voltage?

Tags: led

I think I accidentally applied reverse voltage (+12V to pin 2) to LM3914 in simple 10LED circuit and now only LED1 lights up. Is my LM3914 burned?

Comment: What was V+ (pin 3) connected to at that stage? If 12V as well it would have effectively been 0V, but if you reversed both then you've most likely fried it. Actually forget that, even if a 0V supply then you've probably had voltages on other pins and fried it anyway.

Comment: As PeterJ told, if you have reversed both 12V and GND, then the chip most likely is burnt out.

Comment: yes both pin2 and pin3 was reversed, too bad this chip was soldered straight on without socket

Comment: This question is pointless since the allowable voltage range should be mentioned in the datasheet, and there is no evidence the OP even looked.

Answer (score 2):

If you really reversed pins 2 and 3 you have burned your IC.

As the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) says, just the Input pin (pin 5) is protected against reverse and
overvoltage signals.
[image]

> The simplified LM3914 block diagram is to give the general idea of the
>   circuit's operation. A high input impedance buffer operates with
>   signals from ground to 12V, and is protected against reverse and
>   overvoltage signals. The signal is then applied to a series of 10
>   comparators; each of which is biased to a different comparison level
>   by the resistor string.

Comment: you're right, originally it was a simple O2 sensor tester but I used it to check relay operation in another setup and accidentally switched polarities, as a result LM3914 fried. I should have used a diode as a protection